# Is this a graphics card issue?

Tags: graphics-card

Firstly, I want to say that, first I thought this was a graphics card issue, although i'm not completely sure, so please move this to the appropriate section if i'm wrong.

Recently, my computer has been experiencing huge lag spikes during games, followed by a scrambled boxy version of what was on my screen. It's quite difficult to describe at the bottom of there question are some pictures of what my screen looked like when the issue happened.

The screen was static and I couldnt do anything, both the keyboard and mouse didn't do anything, however as well as this, when I went to shut down my computer via the button, rather than having to hold it down in order to force it, I would only press it for half a second and it would instantly shut down.
This would happen initially during games, becoming more frequent, but when i went to do a virus scan in safe mode, the same thing happened before the scan could finish. It happened a few days ago, then stopped for a bit, but it started again recently. I think this is a graphics card issue, but i'm not completely sure, so any help with finding what this is exactly would be great.

Thanks

[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you tried re-installing the graphics card drivers? Also, just to ensure that you get the best results from people help your, I could put the pictures in your question instead of putting in links to photobucket. It also helps preserve the question and all of its integrity for future reference. I will go ahead and put the pictures in the question for you this time.

Comment: I have recently updated the drivers, however ill reinstall them to be sure. I dont know whether this would be of interest or not, but my graphics card is an AMD Radeon HD 5700.

Comment: It sounds like something is overheating. Do you have another video card to test with?

Comment: Unfortunately i've never bought any videocard on its own, I could pull one out of an old computer that i've no doubt got somewhere, however I did download a program called HWmonitor from Cpuid in order to monitor the temperatures. I did take a short look and everything seemed ok however I wasnt monitoring it during any graphics intensive period on the computer, i'll try to and ill post the results here

Answer (score 0):

This could be any number of causes: graphics card, memory, cpu, motherboard, powersupply, or other hardware.

The computer shutdown instantly when you hit the power button because the CPU is essentially shutdown. So the power button becomes a dead switch.

How old is the computer? My next guess would be this is power supply related.

Comment: Firstly, updating my drivers didnt work, it still happened when I was in the middle of a game.

Comment: (whoops, I accidentaly posted it when I wasnt done yet). Secondly, the computer is about 2 years old. I have never modified it, however recently I did reformat it in order to update my 32-bit windows 7 to 64-bit windows 7.

Comment: If it happens in the middle of the game, the most common culprits are **heat** and **power**.  I'd borrow a fresh power supply and test it.

Comment: Well, I tried running a game, and just before it crashed, the program read 40 degrees Celsius, however I'm not sure if that is accurate as earlier before it crashed it read 43 degrees. However, none of these temperatures seem particularly high.

Comment: Now though, the computer won't even launch. I tried booting it after it crashed, but it just went past the intel screen the. Went black with a blinking underscore. I restarted it again, and it got to the starting windows screen, but it was stuck on that for a while, then it just restarted itself and went back to the blinking underscore. When I restarted it again it offered to run startup repair, I tried startup repair but it didn't do anything, and the cycle just repeated, so basically it won't even boot anymore. (sorry I couldnt put it in message, I ran out of space.